# Order by One column But Push to the end if Another column is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, rank

I'm trying to sort some results based on rank, but I want to push the results without an image to the end.

I have a table with `instructor_profiles` and another `users` table. I'm trying to sort the instructor's profile based on dense rank but would like to show the ones without pictures at the end.

My rank is working fine, but I can't figure it out how to do it.

For example:

```sql
SELECT ts_rank_cd("instructor_profiles"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('english', 'skate')),
 "instructor_profiles".id, 
 "instructor_profiles".title, 
 "instructor_profiles".image, 
 users.avatar
 FROM "instructor_profiles" LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = instructor_profiles.user_id 
 WHERE ("instructor_profiles"."search_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'skate')) 
 ORDER BY 
        ts_rank_cd("instructor_profiles"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('english', 'skate')) desc
 LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Will get to this result:
[image: results]

Then I tried to change the ORDER BY to

```
ORDER BY instructor_profiles.image NULLS LAST,
users.avatar NULLS LAST,
ts_rank_cd("instructor_profiles"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('english', 'skate')) desc
```

But then my sort by the rank is totally messed up:
[image: results 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` in your ordering, something like:

```
 ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN instructor_profiles.image IS NOT NULL 
              OR users.avatar IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 1  
          END ASC,
          ts_rank_cd DESC
```

This doesn't order by the `image` or `avatar`, just by the fact whether or not it is `NULL`, and all that aren't are treated equally and your ranking function will then apply.

Comment: Thanks, it got a little closer but then the rank sort is not working properly, take a look: ![list picture](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2w1j0J2w2c1j1d0Q0n2N/%5B91fe9c338e29c95e99e84e25a7ae1a9d%5D_Image+2019-04-11+at+4.34.20+PM.png)

Comment: I updated the statement to push the results with either `image` or `avatar` to the bottom, instead of first avatar then image.

Comment: Thanks, MarcinJ, but unfortunately it gets me the same result, I'm not sure if we can do this just using regular "order by" because of it sort by one param and then use this new sorted list and then apply the second param to this "new" list. What I want is to sort by rank but push the ones with null images to the end, but the list needs to keep the correct rank sort.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "push the ones with null images to the end, but the list needs to keep the correct rank sort". That's exactly what happens. In your screenshot you marked some rows as "these should go down", but why? The ones below it have NULL avatar or image, so they go below the ones that have it set, as you wanted. With the updated query you'll first get the ones with non-null image & avatar, sorted by your rank, then you'll get the ones with either image or avatar NULL, still sorted by rank. Let me know what the desired output is and it can definitely be sorted out.

Comment: First, thank you much for your time. I imported this content to [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XX3dCfs23Of382jGxnhwUeJejHr_dNGO6O0PFGwKrMs/edit?usp=sharing) and manually reorganized it in the way I want, take a look, or check the [print screen here](https://links.filipe.co/2DaDM95).

I tried to explain it on the screenshot, The thing is, after moving all records with NULL IMAGES I need to keep the sort by the rank. You can see in this example that it went from 3.6 to 0.4 with images, and then 4 to 0.4 without images.

Comment: So you wanted "first the ones with any image, sorted by rank, then the ones without any image, sorted by rank". I understood that if any of the images is missing it should go to the bottom. It's simple enough, I updated my answer and [here's a working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae1c048adc7e00155fd96682db637780) - produces the exact output you posted in Google Sheet :)